# Two Custom Post Types - One WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have been reading constantly through stack exchange and wordpress forums for a solution similar to mine, but I cannot seem to locate what I need so thought I would ask here and see what happens.

I have two custom post types 1. Featured Business 2. Regular Business

When a user visits the website I want them to do a search for a business in a directory I have created.

I can't seem to get the order of the posts to display all of custom post type 1 first followed by custom post type 2.

How can I create a loop which will display all 1.featured business custom post type entries first, then display the 2.regular business custom post type entries second. Then if no 1.featured business entries just display 2.regular business entries as there will always be 2.regular business entries but won't always have entries from 1.featured business.

I hope this makes some sort of sense so that somebody could help me craft a WP_Query or pre_get_posts function to help solve this issue.

At the moment I haven't put any loop code here as nothing works as I want.

Thanks in advance

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has it's own `orderby` field which accepts the type, the below should work:

```
$args = [ 
         'post_type' => ['regular_business', 'featured_business'], 
         'orderby' => ['type' => 'ASC']
        ];

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Depending on if you want the regular business or featured business on top or on the bottom you can change **ASC** to **DESC**.

Also please make sure to change `regular_business` and `featured_business` to your particular post type names correctly.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm! Here is my final code that worked.

`<?php
  $args = array( 
         'post_type'  => array('business', 'featured-business'),
         'orderby'   => array('type' => 'DESC')
        );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
 ?>`

Comment: Great news! Glad I could help